# C# Using Duplicate value parameters in HttpRuntime.Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm adding some recurring batch jobs to the Cache in a .net MVC application and I have a page that checks the cache (and various other places) to check they are either scheduled or currently running.  Currently I only have 1 entry that I add, but in order to future-proof the checks I am proposing to use a common text value for the value parameter when adding the item to the cache. For example

```
HttpRuntime.Cache("item1", "ourcacheitems", .....
HttpRuntime.Cache("item2", "ourcacheitems", .....
```

so on my loop around all the cache items I then check for the value = "ourcacheitems" so I can differentiate what we've added from the system items.
I know that I can't use duplicate keys, but is there any problem in using duplicate values?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem. Maybe this can be useful: you can add any object to the cache, not only strings.